# Basic Playwright setup not working in Angular

Tags: angular, github-actions, playwright

I am looking to automate my Playwright e2e tests that run during my github actions. Its testing a very small and simple Angular App (running v16)

here is my main deployment.yml file

```
name: Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
env:
  AWS_ACCOUNT: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCOUNT }}
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build Angular project
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: "16.x"
          registry-url: "https://npm.pkg.github.com"
          cache: "npm"

      - name: Compile client code
        run: |
          npm ci
          npm run build
          rm -f ./dist/*.map
          cd ./cdk
          npm ci
          cd ..

      - name: Upload build artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: build
          path: ./dist
          retention-days: 1

      - name: Run test
        run: npm run test:ci

      - name: Upload coverage reports to Codecov
        uses: codecov/codecov-action@v3
        env:
          CODECOV_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}

      - name: cdk deploy
        uses: youyo/aws-cdk-github-actions@v2.1.4
        with:
          cdk_subcommand: "deploy"
          cdk_stack: "frontend-riskRoller"
          cdk_args: "--require-approval never"
          working_dir: "./cdk"
          actions_comment: false
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "us-east-1"
  tests_e2e:
    name: Run end-to-end tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci
      - name: Install playwright browsers
        run: npx playwright install --with-deps
      - name: Run tests
        run: npx playwright test
```

I am getting this error here:
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/16834
but do not have the same setup

```
 Run npx playwright test
  npx playwright test
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    AWS_ACCOUNT: ***
[WebServer] - Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
[WebServer] ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
[WebServer] ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Error: Timed out waiting 60000ms from config.webServer.
```

my playwright config is fairly out of the box but I did change the webconfig part

```
export default defineConfig({
  testDir: './tests',
  /* Run tests in files in parallel */
  fullyParallel: true,
  /* Fail the build on CI if you accidentally left test.only in the source code. */
  forbidOnly: true,
  /* Retry on CI only */
  retries: 0,
  /* Opt out of parallel tests on CI. */
  workers: 1,
  /* Reporter to use. See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters */
  reporter: 'html',
  /* Shared settings for all the projects below. See https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions. */
  use: {
    /* Base URL to use in actions like `await page.goto('/')`. */
    // baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',

    /* Collect trace when retrying the failed test. See https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer */
    trace: 'on-first-retry',
  },

  /* Configure projects for major browsers */
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] },
    },

    {
      name: 'firefox',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Firefox'] },
    },

    {
      name: 'webkit',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Safari'] },
    },
  ],

  webServer: {
    command: ' npm run start',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:4200',
    reuseExistingServer: true,
    timeout: 60000,
  },
});
```

any help in getting this working would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer - I made the following changes:

Switched the command from npm run start to ng serve (don't think this helped but documenting it)

```
   webServer: {
    command: ' ng serve',
    url: 'http://localhost:4200',
    reuseExistingServer: true,
    timeout: 60000,
  },
```

then I also switched the url from 127.0.0.1 to localhost and for ease earlier in the config I changed the baseURL to be :

```
  use: {
    /* Base URL to use in actions like `await page.goto('/')`. */
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:4200',
```